# Posicionamento do mouse no centro de um retângulo com pygame.mouse.get_pos()

Tags: python, pygame

Olá!

Li o seguinte código com Pygame:

```
import pygame

PRETO = (0,0,0)
AMARELO = (255,255,0)
VERMELHO = (255,0,0)
VERDE = (0,255,0)
AZUL = (0,0,255)
BRANCO = (255,255,255)

LARGURAJANELA = 500
ALTURAJANELA = 400

pygame.init()

janela = pygame.display.set_mode((LARGURAJANELA, ALTURAJANELA))
label = pygame.display.set_caption("Retang acompanha o mouse com delay_CLOCK")
relogio = pygame.time.Clock()

ret = pygame.Rect(10, 10, 100, 50)

cont = True

while cont:
    relogio.tick(20) # Altere o valor para alterar o delay
    pygame.display.update()
    janela.fill((PRETO))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            cont = False

    (ret.left, ret.top) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    ret.left -= ret.width/2
    ret.top -= ret.height/2

    janela.fill(AMARELO)
    pygame.draw.rect(janela, AZUL, ret)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Eu não entendi esse trecho para centralizar o ponteiro do mouse no retângulo quando há movimento:

```
(ret.left, ret.top) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
ret.left -= ret.width/2
ret.top -= ret.height/2
```

Quando era, apenas, `(ret.left, ret.top) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()`, ok. A posição do ponteiro o mouse é igual a posição left e top do retângulo.

Mas, quando você decrementa o ret.left e o ret.top, por que o mouse fica no centro? O valor de ret.left, por exemplo, não seria o valor atual dele menos a metade da largura?

De fato, eu não entendi. Se alguém puder me explicar eu agradeço. Já pesquisei na web e não achei nada.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Bem tem algumas coisas sobre seu codigo quê são bem estranhas tipo `pygame.display .update` no começo e no final, e `janela.fill` sendo substituido de toda forma, mas acredito que talvez seja um projeto maior.  Mas sobre o quê você perguntou:

`(ret.left, ret.top) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()`
o ponteiro do mouse vai ficar na cordenada x0/y0 do retangulo.

```
ret.left -= ret.width/2
ret.top -= ret.height/2
```

se você tirar o dividido por 2 ("/2") vai ficar nas ultimas cordenadas o seja o contrario de 0/0 (por assim dizer)

E então se você dividir por dois por exemplo width100 / 2 = width50 então ficara no meio da tela. A mesma coisa serve para a altura da tela (height).